# document.getElementById(...) is null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have noticed an awful lot of questions on this subject, however, they all refer to the `<div>` statement not being ready. Mine is. The document.getElementById() functions are not called until a button is clicked.
What is bugging me, is that I have 3 document.getElementById() calls and it's the middle one that is the problem.

My page....

```
    <?php
    (reference to session etc here)
    $user = (array_key_exists('LoggedInUser', $_SESSION)) ? $_SESSION['LoggedInUser'] : '';
    $HeaderLinks = "<A onclick='javascript:LoadPage(\"Admin\");' href='javascript:void(0);'>Home</A> | <A onclick='javascript:LoadPage(\"LogOut\");' href='javascript:void(0);'>Log out</A>"; // home and logout links

    $LoggedInUser = ($user == '') ? '&nbsp;': "Logged in as: <B>$user</B>";
    $HeaderLinks  = ($user == '') ? '&nbsp;': $HeaderLinks;
    ?>
        <BODY>
            <div class='main_disply_space center'> <!-- MAIN DISPLAY SPACE -->
    <!-- HEADER SECTION START -->
                <div class='page_header'> <!-- HEADER -->
                    <div class='title container'>
                        blah blah
                        <div class='subtitle contained'>
                            blah blah
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- HEADER end -->
                <div class='userandlinks'> <!-- USER and LINKS -->
                <div class='user container' id='LoggedInUser'>
                        <?php echo $LoggedInUser; ?>
                        <div class='links contained' id='AdminLinks'>
                            <?php echo $HeaderLinks; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- USER and LINKS end -->
    <!-- HEADER SECTION END -->
    <!-- BODY SECTION START -->
                <div class=body id='ActivePage'> <!-- DISPLAY AREA -->
                &nbsp;
                </div> <!-- DISPLAY AREA end -->
    <!-- BODY SECTION END -->
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION START -->
                <div class='footerlinks' id='FooterLinks'> <!-- LINKS -->
                    <?php echo $HeaderLinks; ?>
                </div> <!-- LINKS end -->
                <div class='copyright'> <!-- COPYRIGHT -->
                    more blah blah
                </div> <!-- COPYRIGHT end -->
    <!-- FOOTER SECTION END -->
            </div> <!-- MAIN DISPLAY SPACE end -->
        </BODY>
```

The javascript...

```
        send = "username=" + user + "&password=" + pwd;
        if(btn === 'Add')
        {
            if(RunPHPFile('AdminUserAdd', send) === '1')
                if(RunPHPFile('UserLogin', send) === '1')
                {
                    // Show who's logged in
                    document.getElementById("LoggedInUser").innerHTML = 'Logged in as: <B>'+user+'</B>';

                    // show home and logout links
                    HLinks = "<A onclick='javascript:LoadPage(\"Admin\");' href='javascript:void(0);'>Home</A> | <A onclick='javascript:LoadPage(\"LogOut\");' href='javascript:void(0);'>Log out</A>";
                    document.getElementById('AdminLinks').innerHTML = HLinks;
                    document.getElementById('FooterLinks').innerHTML = HLinks;
                    LoadPage('Admin');
                }
                else
                    document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Error logging in new user.';
            else
                document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Error adding new user.';
        }
```

I used a couple of try{} catch(){} on the document.getElementById()s to find why it wasn't working.

Heres the puzzel. In the javascript, you can see 3 document.getElementById()'s one after the other, 'LoggedInUser', 'AdminLinks' & 'FooterLinks'. And in the HTML, you can see the corrisponding id=''.
Now, my problem is that the 'LoggedInUser' and 'FooterLinks', both work fine, but the 'AdminLinks' one raises the 'is null' error. I've gone over and over the coding and I can not see what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

You're replacing the contents of `#LoggedInUser`. Guess what's in the `#LoggedInUser` div? That's right - `#AdminLinks`. So `document.getElementById('AdminLinks')` is returning null because - there's no element on the page with that id.

Comment: Thanks for pointing my stupid mistake. I shoud have added another div statement inside the one I id'd and id'd that one instead. cheers